# Change Apache configuration directory?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, hosting

How to change the config directory from :

> /etc/apache2

to

> /data/config/apache2

?

(I'll be using it with GlusterFS to have the configs synchronized across the cluster)

Many thanks.

Comment: Easy Hack. You can create a shortcut in  `/data/config/apache2` and point  it to `/etc/apache2` or vice versa. I meant `symlinks` or symbolic links. I'm not sure whether it will work. But you can give it a try.

Comment: @ynos1234 Thanks , your 'or vice versa' may actually work, I'll put the real files on /data/config/apache2 and the symlinks on /etc/apache2 ; then I'll sync /data/config/apache2 across the cluster with glusterfs. Put your comment into an answer to can choose it. Many thanks.

Comment: Happy that you found my simple answer useful. I'm adding it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suggesting you an easy hack. You can create a shortcut in `/data/config/apache2` and point it to `/etc/apache2` or `vice versa`. I meant `symlinks` or symbolic links.